# Very strange behavior with neo4j OPTIONAL MATCH in a linked list

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a linked list structure of kind:

```
(root:`Desk`)-[:linked_list*0..]->(article:`Article`)-[:linked_list]->...-[:linked_list]->(root:`Desk`)
```

To query all elements of the list I use this query:

```
MATCH (r)-[:linked_list]->(e) 
WHERE ID(r) = {r_id} 
AND r <> e 
RETURN e
```

And it works very well.

But when I try to optional match some relations linked to an `Article`, the query really takes a lot, and I obtain a lot of strange data.

```
MATCH (r)-[:linked_list]->(e) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (e)-[:author]->(u:`User`) 
WHERE ID(r) = {r_id} 
AND r <> e 
RETURN e, [collect(a)] as authors
```

I tried to visualize the result on http://localhost:7474 , and here's a result:

[image: query results]

It seems to fill `r` and `e` with all values of the database.

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you observed has 2 causes:

1. A `WHERE` clause only filters its *immediately preceding* `MATCH` clause.
2. An `OPTIONAL MATCH` clause that fails to match does not remove any results from prior `MATCH` clauses.

Your first `MATCH` clause matches **all** neighboring `r` and `e` nodes (because it is not immediately followed by a `WHERE` clause).

Your second `MATCH` clause *is* filtered by a `WHERE` clause. But because it is an `OPTIONAL MATCH` clause, failure to satisfy the `WHERE` clause does not eliminate any of the matches found by the first `MATCH`.

Therefore, you need to put your `WHERE` clause right after your first `MATCH` clause  (something like @DaveBennett's answer) in order to do the filtering you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you really want to do is something like this instead.  Find the `linked_list` items and then then with each `e` matched perform the optional match.

```
MATCH (r)-[:linked_list]->(e) 
WHERE ID(r) = {r_id} 
AND r <> e
WITH e 
OPTIONAL MATCH (e)-[:author]->(a:`User`) 
RETURN e, collect(a) as authors
```